# Wrong GPO Applied to RDS Session

Tags: group-policy, rds

I am running Win 2012 R2 RDS session-based services with 16 rds users connecting via thin-client RDP session.

I have several GPOs set up to set desktop, manage RemoteFX, background, etc.

13/16 rds sessions are using the correct GPOs, however, 3/6 are using the wrong desktop redirection GPO. They are using settings that were once in place, but no longer.

I've checked assignment settings and nothing seems to be mis-assigned.

I've run gpupdate.exe, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Is there any way to reset the GPO cache/database back to default and then re-run for specific users?

Any ideas as to what would cause just 3/16 rdp users to have this issue, but not the others?

Comment: What are the results of `GPRESULT /USER [domain\]user /r` for the users that have issues?

Comment: Completely normal. All expected GPOs applied, none that I didn't expect. It's like there's a ghost gpo cache that is carrying over a setting that is no longer active.

Comment: Have you tried `GPUPDATE /FORCE /BOOT` from one of the users with issues? This command should clear any cached GPO garbage and pull updated settings. (This will auto-logoff the user, so make sure to close open applications before running)